# How to create CodeFunction2 with IEnumerable<> Type?

Tags: c#, code-generation, envdte

I really need to create something like the following, I am building 2 classes, the first is a class with the name of tableNameAsSingular (i.e AddressEntity) , in my second worker class I need to having something like the following

```
public IEnumerable<AddressEntity> GetAddressEntity()
{
 // the good stuff...
}
```

When creating the Function I have the following..

```
Type t = Type.GetType("IEnumerable<" + tableNameAsSingular + ">");
CodeFunction2 finderFunction = (CodeFunction2)entityServiceClass.AddFunction("Get" + table.Name, vsCMFunction.vsCMFunctionFunction, t, -1, vsCMAccess.vsCMAccessPublic, null);
```

but t is always null

When I do `Type.GetType(tableNameAsSingular)` it returns null too

Any help or pointers would be greatfully received. Also if anyone knows where a plethora of EnvDTE code generation knowledge lives I would be sooo greatful!

---

### Update

I have now tried it just as a string using the following:

```
   public void AddFinderMethod()
    {
        string t = "IEnumerable<" + tableNameAsSingular + ">";
        CodeFunction2 finderFunction = (CodeFunction2)entityServiceClass.AddFunction("Get" + table.Name, vsCMFunction.vsCMFunctionFunction, t, -1, vsCMAccess.vsCMAccessPublic, null);
        // Code here remove as it does not get this far yet.
    }
```

but I get "`IEnumerable<ProductEntity> is not a valid identifier`" error message in the AddFunction Method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have managed to get it working with the following:

```
string returnType = "System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<" + tableNameAsSingular + ">"; 
CodeFunction2 finderFunction = (CodeFunction2)entityServiceClass.AddFunction("Get" + table.Name, vsCMFunction.vsCMFunctionFunction, returnType, -1, vsCMAccess.vsCMAccessPublic, null);
```

Answer (score 3):

The syntax `IEnumerable<T>` is C# syntax, not .NET syntax (which uses back-ticks, counters, etc). What you mean is:

```
Type tableType = Type.GetType(assemblyQualifiedNameToEntity);
Type enumerableType = typeof(IEnumerable<T>).MakeGenericType(tableType);
```

Note that `Assembly.GetType` is usually a better choice, as you can just use namespace-qualified names:

```
Assembly asm = typeof(SomeKnownType).Assembly;
Type tableType = asm.GetType(namespaceQualifiedNameToEntity);
```

Comment: I really appreciate your reply, When you say that Assembly.GetType is the better choice. Are you saying that the second version is the one to use, on its own?

Comment: When I do Type.GetType("Debugging.Catalog.ProductModelEntity") , I am getting null. This I expect is because it is a DSL I am working with and the code generation assembly is not the same as where the code is being generated. It is a Dynamic Type

Comment: Have you completed the dynamic type yet? Or is it still under construction? If completed, then the version starting `Assembly` should work, but the easiest option is to simply keep your dynamic Type objects in a lookup during construction. I've fought this battle - it isn't pretty ;-p

Comment: I am really struggling on how to get my Dynamic Type , any pointers? I have my CodeClass2 object